# Sending animated GIFs with sendPhoto (Telegram bot)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to send an animated GIF with sendPhoto (Telegram's Bot API) with this request:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<chat_id>&photo=http://i.giphy.com/13IC4LVeP5NGNi.gif
```

That method works, as in, I get `ok:true` back, but the image in the chat window is a still snapshot of the moving GIF.

How can I get the animated GIF to show? Is there another method I should use?

Comment: Nowadays method [sendAnimation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendanimation) is the best option.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use the [sendAnimation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendanimation) method for sending a *GIF or H.264/MPEG-4 AVC video without sound*. 
Just use the `animation` parameter for your GIF file.

`sendPhoto` is only used for static images.

Comment: Please, mark this as the correct answer @m52go, as it is the recommended way. Also, even if you send it using sendVideo, you still get a document object back.

Comment: Yes, sure you can use `sendDocument` and it works on desktop, but on the mobile you will face with problem when you see only preview of gif, not a gif at once. If you use `sendVideo` - both good on a desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 14):

use sendVideo method!

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendVideo?chat_id=<chat_id>&video=http://i.giphy.com/13IC4LVeP5NGNi.gif
```

this will work

Comment: OMG BRILLIANT!!!!!!!!!!!!! 

it does work. thanks, not sure why i didn't try it. just marked this as the correct answer.

Comment: This worked for me. sendDocument didn't (I'm using the c# nuget package)

Comment: What if a image or video is from local disc?

Comment: How to run this code in python?