# Send text message via python to the Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have been trying since the morning but earlier there were errors, so i had the direction but now there is no error and even not a warning too..

How code looks like :

```
import requests

def send_msg(text):
token = "TOKEN"
chat_id = "CHATID"
url_req = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage" + "?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + text 
results = requests.get(url_req)
print(results.json())

send_msg("hi there 1234")
```

What is expected output :
It should send a text message

What is the current output :
It prints nothing

It would be great help is someone helps, Thank you all

**Edit : 2**

As the below dependancies were not installed, it was not capable of sending the text .

```
$ pip install flask
$ pip install python-telegram-bot
$ pip install requests
```

Now can somebody help me with sendPhoto please? I think it is not capable of sending image via URL, Thank you all

**Edit 3 **

I found a image or video sharing url from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171347/sending-animated-gifs-with-sendphoto-telegram-bot) but mine image is local one and not from the remote server

Comment: Try `bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, 'URL')` to send photos.

Answer (score 6):

**There is nothing wrong with your code. All you need to do is proper indentation.**

> This error primarily occurs because there are space or tab errors in
> your code. Since Python uses procedural language, you may experience
> this error if you have not placed the tabs/spaces correctly.

**Run the below code. It will work fine :**

```
import requests

def send_msg(text):
   token = "your_token"
   chat_id = "your_chatId"
   url_req = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage" + "?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + text 
   results = requests.get(url_req)
   print(results.json())

send_msg("Hello there!")
```

**To send a picture might be easier using bot library** : `bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, 'URL')`

Note : It's a good idea to configure your editor to make tabs and spaces visible to avoid such errors.

Comment: Kindly have a look over the edited question again and if possible please help

Comment: Replace `your_token` and `your_chatId` with the one you are using and it will work. Let me know if you are still facing issues after trying it. To send photos try : `bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, 'URL')`

Comment: I am successfully abled to send a text message, but not getting how to change it to be able to send photo as i am using url_req and actually do not want it to be url based

Comment: Refer to this : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto . This should help you out.

Comment: I seen that official sendPhoto parameters description .. I am not getting the basic implementation of that via python

Comment: `bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('tests/test.png', 'rb'))` .  Just replace  `tests/test.png` with the image that you have in your local.

Comment: What is bot variable, How to initialise it, Which library to import?

Comment: Install or upgrade python-telegram-bot with : `$ pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade`. I suggest you to first go through the *documentation* to have better understanding about the telegram bot.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```py
import telegram
#token that can be generated talking with @BotFather on telegram
my_token = ''

def send(msg, chat_id, token=my_token):
    """
    Send a mensage to a telegram user specified on chatId
    chat_id must be a number!
    """
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=msg)
```

Comment: Start all code lines with at 4 spaces to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that correctly encoded URL parameters using the popular `requests` library. This is a simple method if you simply want to send out plain-text or Markdown-formatted alert messages.

```py
import requests


def send_message(text):
    token = config.TELEGRAM_API_KEY
    chat_id = config.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID

    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage"
    params = {
       "chat_id": chat_id,
       "text": text,
    }
    resp = requests.get(url, params=params)

    # Throw an exception if Telegram API fails
    resp.raise_for_status()
```

[For full example and more information on how to set up a Telegram bot for a group chat, see README here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/arbitrage-opportunity-tracker).

Below is also the same using asyncio and `aiohttp` client, with throttling the messages by catching HTTP code 429. Telegram will kick out the bot if you do not throttle correctly.

```py
import asyncio
import logging

import aiohttp

from order_book_recorder import config


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def is_enabled() -> bool:
    return config.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID and config.TELEGRAM_API_KEY


async def send_message(text, throttle_delay=3.0):
    token = config.TELEGRAM_API_KEY
    chat_id = config.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID

    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage"
    params = {
       "chat_id": chat_id,
       "text": text,
    }

    attempts = 10

    while attempts >= 0:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url, params=params) as resp:
                if resp.status == 200:
                    return
                elif resp.status == 429:
                    logger.warning("Throttling Telegram, attempts %d", attempts)
                    attempts -= 1
                    await asyncio.sleep(throttle_delay)
                    continue
                else:
                    logger.error("Got Telegram response: %s", resp)
                    raise RuntimeError(f"Bad HTTP response: {resp}")
```